# Modifying an observable collection and using the async pipe, does not update the DOM?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using the async pipe to subscribe to a collection of items in an array. My template looks like the following:

`

```
<ng-container *ngIf="gearItems$ | async as gearItems">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let gearItem of gearItems">
          <app-merchandise-item
            [admin]="isAdmin"
            class="list-item"
            [gearItem]="gearItem"
          >
          </app-merchandise-item>
        </ng-container>
      </ng-container>
```

`I then have the following in my component to capture the stream coming from the service:`

```
gearItems$ = this.merchandiseService.gearItems$;
```

`

I get the `gearItems$` collection through a resolve with the following implementation:

```
MerchandiseService.ts
```

`

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    console.log("Inside of the resolver");
    return (this.gearItems$ = this.http
      .get<GearItem[]>(this.merchandiseUrl)
      .pipe(shareReplay()));
  }
```

`

In the ui I display a delete button for each gear item displayed. When user clicks on that delete button, what I would like to do, is modify the observable collection gearItems$ in the service and have the UI update and reflect the updated collection. Here is my code in my MerchandiseService.ts file which does the filtering.

`

```
deleteGearItem(Id: number): Observable<GearItem[]> {
    // remove gear item
    return (this.gearItems$ = combineLatest([
      this.gearItems$,
      this.http.delete<void>(`${this.merchandiseUrl}/${Id}`, this.headers)
    ]).pipe(
      map(([gearItems, deleted]: [GearItem[], void]) => {
        console.log("Inside delete");
        gearItems = gearItems.filter(gearItem => gearItem.id !== Id);
        return gearItems;
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    ));
```

`

The code inside of the delete method does in fact execute, but nothing is updated in the UI. I have no idea why this is so. Is it because I am not next-ing any values? I thought that the `deleteGearItem(Id: number)` method returns the updated gearItem collection, which should trigger change detection?

Comment: What do you mean "because of your (...)"

Comment: This is probably the cause : `gearItems$ = this.merchandiseService.gearItems$` the two références may be différents after your delete

Comment: doesn't that just create another pointer to the same object? ill try using this.merchandiseService.gearItems$ directly in the template then.

Comment: That is most likely the cause. Is there a better way you would recommend of doing this? When I moved this.merchandiseService.gearItems$ directly into the component it deleted the items correctly, but it also initially, removed all items from the screen, then once the async request completed it brought them back on the scree, but minus the one I deleted.

Comment: As in my answer, use `BehaviorSubject` instead of `shareReplay` to have uniq reference.

Answer (score 1):

`=` made a copy of reference like you can see here :

```
var bob1 = {test: 'test1'} // bob1.test = 'test1'
var bob2 = bob1; // bob2.test = 'test1'
var bob1 = {test: 'test2'}
// bob1.test = 'test2'
// bob2.test = 'test1'
```

So I think it's better to always keep the same reference.

One way to do that is to use a `BehaviorSubject` and emit new values in it after add or delete.

You will be able to export it from your service as `mySubject.asObservable()`.

**What your code have to look like:**

```
private gearItems = new BehaviorSubject<GearItem[]>([]);
gearItems$ = gearItems.asObservable();

resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): void {
    this.gearItems$ = this.http
      .get<GearItem[]>(this.merchandiseUrl)
      .pipe(tap(response => this.gearItems.next(response));
}


deleteGearItem(Id: number): void {
    const newGearItems = this.gearItems.getValue().filter(gearItem => gearItem.id !== Id);
    this.gearItems.next(newGearItems);
}
```

Comment: I think shareReplay creates either a behavior or replay subject under the hood anyway.

Comment: You are right but it returns an observable so you can't update the value manually. You need your own subject to do that.

Comment: How would you recommend I structure my code then? Can you modify your answer to be more relevant to my code with from my question?

Comment: If you want to return an observable in your functions you can add `return this.gearItems$;` at the end of each one

Comment: Where are you getting `gearItems.filter` the gearItems collection from? did you mean to do this.gearItems.getValue().filter()?

Comment: Yes exactly. sorry